# mysql incorrect key file

Tags: mysql, file, crash, key

I am getting this error in mysql. I tried to repair it many times, but still its persisting. I also repaired all the tables.

```
morein_db/categories.MYI'; try to repair it
110716  9:58:16 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Incorrect key file for table './morein_db/categories.MYI'; try to repair it
110716  9:58:16 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Incorrect key file for table './morein_db/categories.MYI'; try to repair it
110716  9:58:16 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Incorrect key file for table './morein_db/products_stock.MYI'; try to repair it
110716  9:58:16 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Incorrect key file for table './morein_db/products_stock.MYI'; try to repair it

110716 10:01:03 [ERROR] Got an error from thread_id=3586, /builddir/build/BUILD/mysql-5.5.10/storage/myisam/mi_write.c:222
```

Answer (score 1):

Shutdown MySQL server, change the directory to morein_db while in the MySQL *datadir* and execute the myisamchk utility

```
myisamchk --silent --force --fast --update-state --key_buffer_size=64M --sort_buffer_size=64M --read_buffer_size=1M --write_buffer_size=1M *.MYI
```

This assumes you have more than 64M of available RAM. If you increase these buffers the repair will be faster. You can check the details for the (very handy) myisamchk utility here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/myisamchk.html